# Apache Commons FTP storeFileStream returns null

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

I am trying to upload a file in android to an FTP server using the apache.commons.ftp library.

Note: I am using `storeFileStream` so that I can track the progress of the upload.

```java
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(localFile);
OutputStream outputStream = ftpClient.storeFileStream(remoteFile);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int bytesRead;
logMessage("Starting to upload file");

while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    total += bytesRead;
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); //output stream is null here
    latestPercentDone = (int) ((total / (float) totalMegaBytes) * 100);
    if (percentDone != latestPercentDone) {
        percentDone = latestPercentDone;
        publishProgress(""+percentDone);
    }
}
inputStream.close();
outputStream.close();
ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
```

I am using the speedtest.tele2.net server for testing. Using an anonymous login.

The log keeps saying the outputstream is null.

EDIT: Using what Martin Prikryl and getting the error code, i found the problem to be the location of the remote file.

Upload to a location rather than a directory.

For example if the file is caled `item1.txt` the remote file should be `/item1.txt` or `/someFolder/AnotherFolder/item1.txt` rather than `/someFolder/AnotherFolder/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`FTPClient.storeFileStream` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFileStream(java.lang.String)) can return `null`:

> An OutputStream through which the remote file can be written. **If the data connection cannot be opened (e.g., the file does not exist), null is returned (in which case you may check the reply code to determine the exact reason for failure).**

Though the "file does not exist" note is nonsense for upload, it's obviously a copy-and-paste error from the [`.retrieveFileStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream(java.lang.String)) (download).

---

Use the [`.getReplyCode`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#getReplyCode()) and [`.getReplyString`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#getReplyString()), to see what went wrong.