# Apache FTPClient: Write text from memory to file on FTP server

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons-net

My Android app (min API 24, target API 27, Java 8) uses Apache's `FTPClient` to connect to an FTP server. At the moment I'm trying to write some text to a file on the server (the file doesn't exist on the phone!) but failing:

```
login(); //logs in and leaves the connection open
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

if(ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(folder)) {
    OutputStream os = ftpClient.storeFileStream(File.separator+filename);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter((new OutputStreamWriter(os,StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    bw.write(text);
    bw.close();

    if(ftpClient.completePendingCommand()) {
        //Success!
    } else {
        //Failed
    }
} else {
    //Show error because folder doesn't exist
}
```

The file usually doesn't already exist on the server and, while it is created, it's always empty.

The log for it:

```
CWD 
250 CWD command successful.
PWD
257 "/" is current directory.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode ([IP here]).
STOR /blabla9.txt
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
226 Transfer complete. [called because of "completePendingCommand()"]
```

**Question:** How do I write text to a file using the library, creating a new file beforehand (if necessary)?

---

***Edit:*** Instead I also tried to save the text to External Storage, then upload the whole file:

```
login(); //logs in and leaves the connection open
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

if(ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(folder)) {
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    boolean result = ftpClient.storeFile(filename, bis);
    bis.close();

    if(result) {
        //Success!
    } else {
        //Failed
    }
} else {
    //Show error because folder doesn't exist
}
```

This works but it's only a temporary solution because it requires writing the file to External Storage first, then deleting it again after the upload.

The log for this version:

```
CWD 
250 CWD command successful.
PWD
257 "/" is current directory.
TYPE A
200 Type set to A.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode ([IP here]).
STOR blabla11.txt
125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
226 Transfer complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

For me your code works, so I do not know why it does not for you.

Anyway, as the [`FTPClient.storeFile`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFile(java.lang.String,java.io.InputStream)) works you – You can use that with an in-memory stream, like this:

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
ftpClient.storeFile(filename, is);
```

---

The answer to your original question is here:
[Apache Commons FTP storeFileStream returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31550862/850848)

---

*Btw, I'm pretty sure the documentation is wrong. It is ok to call [`FTPClient.storeFileStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFileStream(java.lang.String)) when the file does not exist.*

Answer (score 0):

As MartinPrikryl already mentioned in the comments, don't call `enterRemotePassiveMode`, it was the reason `OutputStream os` was `null` every time.

What I did to fix the problem (file was created but not written to):

1. I removed the `BufferedReader` as it's not necessary.
2. The `text` I use looked okay but it is worth checking that it's still okay right before sending. This is because building a lot in Android Studio (I've also experienced this in other IDEs) can get variables "stuck" with their old value, which can be fixed by cleaning the project and/or restarting Android Studio.

The working code:

```
login(); //logs in and leaves the connection open
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

if(ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(folder)) {
    OutputStream os = ftpClient.storeFileStream(File.separator+filename);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    osw.write(text);
    osw.close(); //Better use this in a "finally"

    if(ftpClient.completePendingCommand()) {
        //Success!
    } else {
        //Failed
    }
} else {
    //Show error because folder doesn't exist
}
```

The first paragraph inside the `if` can also be replaced by MartinPrikryl's code (`storeFile` instead of `storeFileStream`).